# Why do I have to specify a Uri for my service reference?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, web-services

I have a WCF service reference in my silverlight application called WCF_Service. Yet, whenever I want to use it in my code, I have to specify the Uri for the reference as such:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "WcfDataService.svc");
WCF_Service.Entities context = new WCF_Service.Entities(uri);
```

Why do I need to specify the Uri? I know it is necessary, but doesn't the service reference know where this service is located to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the service reference contains a Uri that was used when you added it and it automatically reused when you update the reference - this is for convenience only though.

You can use the same type of service from many different end points - it's just a matter of reconfiguring what Uri to use (i.e. switch from testing to production server). And that's why you as a consumer have to supply the end point - imagine using the same service from two different servers - you don't want to add *two* references to your project in this case - right?

Comment: That makes sense. Why doesn't it require a Uri if it is a traditional web service and not a WCF one, then?

Comment: If I remember correctly for asmx it defaults to the reference/Uri configured in your web.config but you can override this by setting the `Url` property - I would argue you almost always want to do that.